# Is there any way to set the status code 301 to the notfoundpage component in angular 14?

Tags: javascript, angular

Problem is that we have the set the status code 301 whenever user redirect to not found page in angular 14.Please suggest a way to do it in Angular 14.

I refer this link [How can you return status code 404 from angular PageNotFoundComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135184/how-can-you-return-status-code-404-from-angular-pagenotfoundcomponent) which says this is not possible but is there any way to do it?Also I refer this https://skynix.co/resources/how-to-set-404-status-code-in-angular but this solution was not working in Angular 14.